# Wordpress multiple / exclusive posting pages

Tags: wordpress

I want a site with a separate News and Blog page, ie only news posts are dispayed on news pages and non news posts on blog pages. Also archive lists, category lists, etc for each page must only display relevant posts. Seems like a common requirement, but using the WP documentation, I keep going around in circles!!! Is there a simple way to do this, without getting into multiple blogs, eg using categories.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.

First, you will need to create custom page template. Refer to [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) to see how to create it.

Second, on that page (you can copy from your page.php/index.php, the important part is:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Find that piece and add this code just right above that code:

```
query_posts('cat=3&paged='.get_query_var( 'paged' ));
```

Things to note from above `query_posts` snippet is:

- **cat**: this is the category ID you want to query. To easily see what ID is on a particular category, you can use [ShowID for Post/Page/Category/Tag/Comment](http://ounziw.com/2010/02/05/showid/) plugin.
- **paged**: Paged will allow your custom page to handle next & prev navigations, which is handled by [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) and [prev_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link). As for [get_query_var( 'paged' )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) is function to get what page's page you currently see.

Hope that helped.

<shamelessplug>
I blogged it [here](http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/10/30/cara-menampilkan-suatu-kategori-pada-page-tersendiri/) (in *Bahasa Indonesia*, which you can easily translate using google translate).
</shamelessplug>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you say this is the easy bit which I've already discovered. But it doesn't cater for the blog page which includes all posts/categories except news ones? Also how do you make widgets like Categories, Archive, Recent Posts and Recent comments specific to Blog and News?.

Comment: by 'the blog page' do you mean is the front page?

Comment: No I mean the main posts page, the front page doesn't have to be this. Basically I want a main posts page and a separate news posts page (ie news posts don't appear on main posts and vice versa).

Comment: then all you have to do is, create 2 different page template. One for main post, one for news and set your navigation to point to these page.